# C# Registry key assignement is null

Tags: c#

I'm busy creating a little application for my self and others but I'm kinda stuck here.

I want to get a value of the register 'regedit' with an path. but the value 'RegistryKey' is always null even when I copy the path from the regedit is..

```
private bool HasKey
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                string path = @"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0002";
                using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(path, false))
                {
                    if(key != null)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

I only want to write a bool function that he has found the key.. but the variable 'key' is always null.

Comment: What have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Should your path perhaps start at `\SYSTEM` since you're opening it as a subkey of `RegistryHive.LocalMachine`?

Comment: thank you for the answer - James Thrope!!!! didn't saw that i actually did that :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string path = @"\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0002";
using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{
    using (var subKey = key.OpenSubKey(path, false))
    {
        if (subKey != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me but someone else found the answer.. but tried this as well works like a charm.. anyway have a great day!!!